# Drupal 7 Getting two titles in Teaser View Mode

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting two titles in Teaser View Mode in Drupal 7.
Can you please help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to describe your situation a little more thoroughly. Is it for all content types? Do you have the separate Teaser view mode turned on, or is it going to Default? What fields are in the view mode? Are you overriding any theme templates? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed "Exclude Node Title" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) in Drupal and gave the settings in conmfiguration-> Content authoring -> Exclude node Title section to exclude title for a particular view mode.